# Bootstrap3 - Removed container-fluid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Why they removed container-fluid class in bootstrap3 version ?
How can manage full width layout ?

Comment: Ask them why they removed it...

Comment: they are still in RC versions, and for that, plenty change between versions, for example see all it was change from RC1 to today's RC2 - http://blog.getbootstrap.com/2013/08/13/bootstrap-3-rc2/

Comment: Nope, they removed the flui version since the fixed version is build upon a fluid version. In simplified terms

Comment: @ balexandre thanks for reply , Its means they are still building , its not completed yet http://getbootstrap.com , Right ? And is it good building html with this version ?

Comment: @ AndreZimpel So is it good building html with this version ?

Comment: This pretty much covers all of the changes done or in-progress for v.3: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/6342

Comment: @ShibinRagh I'm using bootstrap 3 sind half a year now. Of course things changed and will change until the official release, but I needed the ability to design mobile first. Everything works fine for me. But you need to know that if you use the rc for a production project it could be hard to update to the official release.

Comment: Why should this question b opinioin-based? @TiesonT.

Comment: @AndreZimpel Simple; the OP is asking StackOverflow users to speak the motivations of those in charge of maintaining Bootstrap, something which we can't and shouldn't do. See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: @TiesonT. Okay, he asked why they removed it without knowing that it is still in there. But the second question is about how to get fue fluid full with layout. This is not opinion based. I think the question should be edited instead.

Comment: @AndreZimpel  Sorry for late reply ;) , I didnt edit my question

Answer (score 4):

Bootstrap Version 3 is entirely based on a fluid-width system, meaning there are no more pixel based widths, it's all percentages now.  So you can control everything through your use of a container or not.  To achieve a full width page, all you would have to do is not include a .container div.

On the flip side, you can force bootstrap into a fixed layout using a .container div.

Comment: container-fluid class is not removed,You can check on http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the .container with a fixed with. The Bootstrap 3 grid is build on percentages. e.g. `.col-1` has a width of `width: 8.333333333333332%;`

Removing .container makes it "automatically" fluid.